# how to get the pure text and selected option in a p-tag?

Tags: javascript, html

After selecting 5 and 2, does any solution for how could get a string output like: 5 greater than 2 ?

```html
<p class="showTxt" id="showTxt">

  <select size="2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
  <p> greater than</p>
  <select size="1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: You could use a hidden form element which has the value "greater than" as well, if this goes to server-side code. In pure JavaScript you can give the p tag an id or a unique class and select it using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
function showText(ele) {
  document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("1").options[document.getElementById("1").selectedIndex].text+" is greater than "+ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<p class="showTxt" id="showTxt">

  <select size="2" id="1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
  <p> greater than</p>
  <select size="1" onchange="showText(this)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="2"></p>
```